# Show one element if another is above a certain height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a following HTML:

```
<span class="day-number">{{day-number}}</span>
<div class="event-box">
  <div class="event-container">
  </div>
  <div class="more-events">more ...</div>
</div>
```

Event-container is filled with an unknown number of `.event` elements like the following:

```
<div class="event">{{event-name}}</div>
```

I want to show or hide the `.more` element based on if the `.event-container` has a height of over `76px` (equal to the height of four `.event` elements stacked).

The styling for the above elements:

```
.event {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: .85em;
    line-height: 1.3;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #3a87ad;
    background-color: #3a87ad;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: whitesmoke;
    padding: 0 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.event-box {
    max-height: 76px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.event-box .more-events {
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 10px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

No styling for `.event-container`

I can do what I want with Javascript (jQuery):

```
$(".event-box").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.children(".event-container").height() > 76){
        $this.children(".more-events").css("display", "block");
    } else {
        $this.children(".more-events").css("display", "");
    }
});
```

And run that every time a make a change, but I'd rather do it with CSS.

Is this possible? Maybe with pseudo elements or media queries or something?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/pitaj/LjLxuhx2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If changing the markup is acceptable there is a possibility to achieve a somewhat similarly looking page without using `JavaScript` to show or hide, here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ashkan_/3a1y7b24/2/)

I have removed `<div class="more-events">more ...</div>` line and made elements of `event` class to get hide when it is necessary I also made them to appear when hovering over `more ...` .

The CSS I have added:

```
.event:nth-child(n){
    display: none;
}
.event:nth-child(1),.event:nth-child(2),.event:nth-child(3),.event:nth-child(4){
    display: block;
}
.event:nth-child(5){
    text-indent: -9999px; 
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.event:nth-child(5)::before{
    position: absolute;    
    text-indent: 0px; 
    content: "more ...";
    display: block;
}
.event:nth-child(5):hover{
    position: static;
    text-indent: 0; 
    border: 1px solid #3a87ad;
    background-color: #3a87ad;
    color: whitesmoke;        
}
.event:nth-child(5):hover::before{
    display:none;
}
.event:nth-child(5):hover ~ .event:nth-child(n){
    display: block;
}
```

And for `.event-box` class I have commented out `max-height: 76px;` because in my browser 76px was not equal to the height of four `.event` elements stacked. Also removed `update` function.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it's possible using css only. but for better approach in what you are trying to do.instead of using `max-height` for `.event-box` I use this css which is add `display:none` to +4.event on your event container:

```
.event-box .event-container .event:nth-child(n+5){
    display: none;
}
```

and now when it's more than 4 .event your more text appears. **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LjLxuhx2/3/)**

**UPDATE:**

[**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LjLxuhx2/5/) I make little change in you js as well and make it more professional,

Comment: On line 4, add `eventcount=4;`. Or instead do like this: http://jsfiddle.net/djfymgpx/1/

Answer (score 0):

while you are using template to render the page, maybe you can do it as follow

```
<div class="event-container">
{{#each events}}
  <div class="event">{{event-name}}</div>
{{/each}}
</div>
{{#if canshowmore}}
<div class="more-events">more ...</div>
{{/if}}
```

and

```
function canshowmore() {
  return events.length >= 4;
}
```

Comment: I'm not using a template, I'm rendering the entire page with JavaScript.